# Limits number of automation in platform

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, limits

1800 automations are executed per day on my SFMC.
That's just over 630,000 automations per year.

Salesforce told me that I was exceeding the annual cap on the number of automations on my contract.
I was never aware of this limit. Has anyone experienced the same thing or has any info to share with me?

This is not a technical question. I know. But considering the size of the community, I ask my question here, it seemed interesting to me.

Thanks for your feedback

Comment: This would be in your contract with number of api calls/ storage/ automation I would recommend reviewing this. But this is a first I've heard of enforcement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This limit is documented here:

https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/mc_email_journey_pricing_sheet.pdf

[image]

Second what EazyE says, first time I hear someone being called out for it. Given that you are 6 times over the top edition's contractual limit, it's actually rather comforting to hear that there is SOME enforcement.

Comment: Thank you for the document... the worst is that I have a corporate edition :-)